# Inconsistency in residue calculation?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

We know that the residue of a function $f(z)$ at a simple pole $z_0$ can be calculated by:

$$\lim_{z \rightarrow z_0}[(z-z_0)f(z)] \tag{1}$$

However while reading K.F Riley Mathematical Methods for Physicist, question 24.15. Given the function:

$$f(z) = \frac{\exp(imz)}{(z+i)(z-i)(2z+i)(2z-i)}$$

I notice that the solutions calculated the residues as

$$\lim_{z \rightarrow \frac{i}{2}} \biggl[(2z-i)\frac{\exp(imz)}{(z+i)(z-i)(2z+i)(2z-i)} \biggr] = \frac{-2ie^{-m/2}}{3} \tag{2}$$

rather than

$$\lim_{z \rightarrow \frac{i}{2}}\biggl[(z - \frac{i}{2})\frac{\exp(imz)}{4(z+i)(z-i)(z+ \frac{i}{2})(z-\frac{i}{2})} \biggr] = \frac{-ie^{-m/2}}{3} \tag{3}$$

I know $(3)$ is the correct solution rather than $(2)$ because it follows the form given by $(1)$. But I cannot wrap my head around why $(2)$ is incorrect since both $(2)$ and $(3)$ are essentially doing the same thing. Is there a reason why?

Comment: Because $(2z-i)= 2(z-\frac i2) \neq (z-\frac i2)$. So, you get an extra factor of $2$.

Comment: @trancelocation Thanks! But I was wondering more of the mechanics behind it. Like why it absolutely MUST BE $z - z_0$

Comment: The residue is the coefficient of $(z-z_0)^{-1}$ in the Laurent expansion about $z=z_0$. So, to get exactly this coefficient you need to use $z-z_0$. In what form you leave the remaining function term does not really matter, as long as you can cancel out the $z-z_0$.

Comment: Just go to the definition of residue. Take the example $f(z)=\frac  1 {(2z-1)}$, for example. What happens if you take the limit of $(2z-1)f(z)$ as $z \to \frac  1 2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you ask about the "mechanics" of the calculation:

- Since there is a simple pole at $z_0$ you can write $f(z) = \frac{a_{-1}}{z-z_0}+g(z)$ where $g$ is holomorphic in a disc around $z_0$.
- $a_{-1}$ is the searched for residue. So, to get this residue you need to calculate $\lim_{z\to z_0}((z-z_0)f(z)) = \lim_{z\to z_0}(a_{-1}+(z-z_0)g(z)) = a_{-1}$.

Now, as in your case, if you take instead any $cz-d=c(z-\frac dc)=c(z-z_0)$ $(c\neq 0)$, the limit would be 
$$\lim_{z\to z_0}((cz-d)f(z)) = c\lim_{z\to z_0}((z-z_0)f(z))$$ $$ = c\lim_{z\to z_0}(a_{-1}+(z-z_0)g(z)) = ca_{-1}$$

Note, that in your special case

$$f(z) = \frac{\exp(imz)}{(z+i)(z-i)\color{blue}{(2z+i)(2z-i)}} = \frac{\exp(imz)}{\color{blue}{4}(z+i)(z-i)\color{blue}{(z+\frac i2)(z-\frac i2)}}$$

So, in way $(2)$ of calculating the residue you cancel out the factor $(2z-i)$ but at the same time you multiply the residue by $2$.

Comment: Very Nice! Thank you!

Comment: @AkiraD.Soul : You are welcome :-)